# How to call multiple endpoints Using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

When we use reteofit We create a POJO class and one Interface that contains multiple endpoints then we create Retrofit instance to make network call .
  If we have a multiple endpoints in an interface then to call them as per user request using single Retrofit Instance .
  How can do that can anyone provide the Example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly. If you want to use the same instance with your endpoints or the same instance of retrofit - you may want to take advantage of singleton pattern or use [dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) and put to use @Singleton annotation.

Here you are some [tutorial](https://adityaladwa.wordpress.com/2016/05/09/dagger-2-with-retrofit-and-okhttp-and-gson/) that seems sufficient for starting.